# WHat is an example of a countable subset of $[0,1]$ whose Jordan content is 1 and Lebesgue measure is 0?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

E.Stein Real analysis p.41

> Exhibit a countable subset $E\subset [0,1]$ such that $J(E)=1$ while $m*(E)=0$.
>
> Here, $m*$ denotes the outer Lebesgue measure and $J$ denotes the Jordan content.

What would be this set?

Comment: The Jordan content of a set equals the Jordan content of the closure of the set. Can you think of a countable subset of $[0,1]$ whose closure is equal to $[0,1]$ (and explain why such a set will have the properties you want)?